# Как узнать причину срабатывания onBlur

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

На форме есть `div`, в котором организован выпадающий список, который появляется если пользователь нажимает на `input#finder`. Мне нужно, что бы этот список закрывался, если пользователь нажал мимо этого дива. При этом если пользователь нажал на `input#finder` - див со списком исчезать не должен.
В приложении используются Angular и jQuery.

```
<input id="finder" type="text">
<div class="finder-list">
  <ul>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: добавьте ваш код в вопрос

Comment: @DenniLa2, если ответ принят, нажмите на зеленую галочку - надо иметь как можно больше закрытых вопросов. Если не принят - что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы предложил действовать иначе.

Вам надо создать обработчик кликов, привязанный к документу. Т.е. обработчик, который бы запускался при ЛЮБОМ клике, где угодно на странице.
Внутри обработчика:

1. выяснить открыт ли список.
   и если открыт
2. выяснить, какой элемент вызвал клик. Если это НЕ `input#finder` - закрыть список

Что-то типа такого:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if ($('#id-списка]:visible').length) {
        if ($(event.target).attr('id')!='finder') {
             [спрятать список]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: а разве это условие когда-нибудь может быть `true`?  вы же разные объекты сравниваете

Comment: ну а если клик будет на `input#finder`, что будет в `event.taget`?

Comment: не важно :-) `$('input#finder') == $('input#finder')` - это выражение всегда `false` - потому что объекты jQuery разные,

Comment: тут намного проще проверить атрибут id у таргета, да и быстрее

Comment: да-да... уже правлю :)

Comment: вполне бы сработало и `event.target.id` :-D не обязательно всегда использовать jQuery :)

Comment: Кстати, сработает и при нажатии на сам список.